# execute first task from first host group1 and second task from second host group1 in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

We have 3 different task in yaml file.
We need to execute task1 and task2 in x.x.x.1 IP and task 3 in x.x.x.2 IP (This should be in parallel)
Then need to run same 3 task - task1 and task2 in x.x.x.3 IP and task 3 in x.x.x.4 IP (This should be in parallel)

**Inventory file:**

```
[Group1]
x.x.x.1
x.x.x.2

[Group2]
x.x.x.3
x.x.x.4
```

yml file:

```yaml
    --
    - hosts: all
      gather_facts: false
      become: true
    
      tasks:
        - name: fetch x pid
          ignore_errors: yes
          shell: "ps -eaf | grep processname1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'"
          register: x_pid
    
        - name: kill x process
          ignore_errors: yes
          shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
          with_items:
            - "{{ x_pid.stdout_lines }}"
         
        - name: service stop
          service:
            name: service1
            state: stopped
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Where is your playbook ?

Comment: Put your tasks in roles so that you can reuse them. Create more groups so you can differentiate "slave" and "master" servers (I really don't know how to call them since I have no idea what your are trying to do exactly). Then create 4 different plays to target the relevant server(s) and play the relevant roles on each of them.

Comment: alternativelly, if you are sure your groups will only contain 2 servers every time and that the order is always relevant, you can target `Group1[0]` in first play (kill processes roles) then `Group1[1]` in second play (stop service role), then `Group2[0]` in third etc....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It seems you want to plays and to distinguish between hosts where processes should be killed and those where service should be stopped.

inventory

```
[Group1]
1.1.1.1 processes=True
1.1.1.2 service=True

[Group2]
1.1.1.3 processes=True
1.1.1.4 service=True
```

playbook

```
---

- hosts: Group1
  gather_facts: &gather_facts false
  become: &become true
  strategy: &strategy free

  tasks:
    - &fetch_x_pid
      name: fetch x pid
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: "ps -eaf | grep processname1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'"
      register: x_pid
      when: processes | default(False)

    - &kill_x_process
      name: kill x process
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: "kill -9 {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ x_pid.stdout_lines }}"
      when: processes | default(False)

    - &service_stop
      name: service stop
      service:
        name: service1
        state: stopped
      when: service

- hosts: Group2
  gather_facts: *gather_facts
  become: *become
  stragegy: *strategy

  tasks:
    - <<: *fetch_x_pid
    - <<: *kill_x_process
    - <<: *service_stop
```

after yaml anchor expantion `yq -y '.' <file>` it should be like this:

```
---
- hosts: Group1
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  strategy: free
  tasks:
    - name: fetch x pid
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: ps -eaf | grep processname1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
      register: x_pid
      when: processes | default(False)
    - name: kill x process
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: kill -9 {{ item }}
      loop: '{{ x_pid.stdout_lines }}'
      when: processes | default(False)
    - name: service stop
      service:
        name: service1
        state: stopped
      when: service | default(False)
- hosts: Group2
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  stragegy: free
  tasks:
    - name: fetch x pid
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: ps -eaf | grep processname1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
      register: x_pid
      when: processes | default(False)
    - name: kill x process
      ignore_errors: true
      shell: kill -9 {{ item }}
      loop: '{{ x_pid.stdout_lines }}'
      when: processes | default(False)
    - name: service stop
      service:
        name: service1
        state: stopped
      when: service | default(False)
```

Comment: Instead of `ps -eaf` kung-fu, you can try `pgrep processname1`, see `man pgrep`, or directly `pkill`.